# Trying to change selected indicator icon in bootstrap-select multiselect dropdown

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, dropdown, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

[Current Icon that I'd like to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80VXy.png)

[To maybe something like this (a separate icon in the same library)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akelw.png)

Working on a multi-select dropdown using bootstrap-select and the checkmark is killing me but I want some form of indication that it has been selected.

[I'd love something like this but it doesn't seem doable with bootstrap 4 (which the rest of the site is)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3rOL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add your class with the desired style. However you can watch this video for more details and do the necessary changes you need:

https://youtu.be/rEwsKL4Elng